# Source code does not pick my changes while executing locally

Tags: cucumber-java

I am trying to debug an error and I added logging and commented few lines of code. But when I run from the cucumber feature file; these changes to the source code has no effect.
IntelliJ + Java

I tried updating IntelliJ, update Gherkin & Cucumber for Java plugins; delete files in .m2 folder &  reimport the the mvn project , Cloned the project again and tried to run tests
Nothing seems to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the **test scope** was missing in the cucumber-java (or cucumber-java8) dependency. Once I updated my pom.xml and added the test scope to those dependencies, it started working as expected.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```